# Update a section of a connection string but not the whole string

Tags: sql, vba, excel

My spreadsheets have a connection to SQL for source data. Since it is a new year I need the year part of the query to read 1/1/14 instead of 1/1/13. However the identification part of the query is unique to each workbook. I cannot find a way to update just the section of the connection string where the date is written without updating the entire connection string - which would then make the unique identification of all other workbooks be the same as the one I record in the macro.

In the example below I want the macro to change the `RVU_all.Post_date>=` line to 1/1/2014 and that is all. Not have the `wrvu_all.NPI=` be in the macro (thus making my macro useless on other workbooks for different people but the same task).

```vb
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "G:\(Where I store my file)   
, UpdateLinks:=0 
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from XXXXXX").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT (data I'm looking for) 
"FROM (My Sql Table)" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (w" _
    , _
    "RVU_all.Post_date>={ts *'2014-01-01 00:00:00'*}) AND (wRVU_all.NPI='UniqueNumber')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY wRVU_all.Post_date" _
    )
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .Connection = Array(Array( _
    "My Connection string to the table" _
    ), Array("BASE=XXXXXX"))
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .SourceDataFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from XXXXXXX")
    .Name = "Query from XXXXXXXX"
    .Description = ""
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from XXXXXXX").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do something like:

```
.commandtext(1)=replace(.commandtext(1),"your original date","your new date")
```

That should do the job!

Comment: I tried to put that in place of everything after .backgroundQuery = False all the way down to End with and it gave me a run time error. Unless I copied it into the wrong area that didn't work

Comment: What I assumed was that commandtext(1) is a string. this may not be the case, hence Type mismatch. Try replace(cstr(.commandtext(1)),"your original date","your new date"). It is quite difficult to debug your code like this, as I cannot run it...

Comment: won't let me run the macro it saying there is a compile error expected: =        I typed in:                                 replace(cstr(.commandtext(1)),"2013-01-01","2014-01-01").

Comment: Again, as I said before, I am not sure what the type of the commandtext(1) is. This should represent the second instance in the Array. You want to replace the string, and replace command is replacing the string. Try to use watch to understand what the type is and why you get the compile error...

Comment: I am sorry, but I was expecting at least some basic VBA knowledge from you. Variable Types are: String, Integer, Double, Object, ... (dim var as Type). Then when you rightclick on an object in VBA code you can usually add it to watch (rightclick and then Add Watch) this will tell you what the type is. The array element you are trying to change is of a specific type and you need to change it and keep the type. Replace works with strings, but not with variants, so you need to do some type checks yourself to make it work.